# Prove that $aKa^{−1} =\{aka^{−1}|k∈K\}$ is a normal subgroup of H.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let G be a group, a ∈ G, and let H and K be subgroups of G. Suppose further that K ▹ H and
H▹G. Prove that $aKa^{−1} =\{aka^{−1}|k∈K\}$ is a normal subgroup of H.  This was a problem that was brought up in a class but we ran out of time for the professor to walk us through it.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please, consider updating your question to include what you have tried and where you are getting stuck. That way, people on this site will know exactly what help you need.

Comment: I guess you mean $K\lhd H$ and $H\lhd G$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a hint:

We know that $\{aka^{-1}:k\in K\}\subset H$ because $k\in H$ and $H$ is normal in $G$.  Once you have shown that $\{aka^{-1}:k\in K\}$ is a subgroup of $H$, what can you say about $hbh^{-1}$ for $b\in\{aka^{-1}:k\in K\}$ and $h\in H$?